# How can I take the string of names and preferences & add them to the dictionary with names as the key?

Tags: python, string, dictionary, methods

My code as it is right now looks like this:

```
def read_in_movie_preference():
    """Read the move data, and return a 
    preference dictionary."""
    preference = {}
    movies = []
    
    # write code here:
    
    file_location="./data/"
    f = open(file_location+"preference.csv","r")
    df = f.readlines()
    
    #names as keys and prefrences
    for line in df:
        name = line[1].strip("\n").split(",")
        prefs = line[2:].strip("\n").split(",")
        preference[line[1]] = line[2:]
    
    #print(test)
    
    #movie names`
    movietitles = df[0].strip("\n").split(",")
    for movie in movietitles:
        movie=movie.rstrip()
    #can't seem to get rid of the spaces at the end    
    movies+=movietitles[2:]
            
        
    print(movies)
       
    return [movies, preference]
```

I cant seem to get the movie titles into the list without spaces at the end of some of them & I also cant add the names and preferences into the dictionary... I am supposed to do this task with basic python and no pandas .. very stuck would appreciate any help!

the dictionary would have names as keys and the preference numbers in number format instead of strings so it would theoretically look like this:
key:     pref:
dennis, 0 1 0 1 0 ect

[![enter image description here][1]][1]this is what the data set looks like

here is the data pasted:

Comment: I can try to do that!

Comment: So the issue is that you are using `rstrip` on a copy of the data but never apply it to the original. replace with `movietitles = [movie.rstrip() for movie in movietitles]`

Comment: "I cant seem to get the movie titles into the list without spaces at the end of some of them" In your own words, what is the intent of the lines `name = line[1].strip("\n").split(",")` and `prefs = line[2:].strip("\n").split(",")`? Does the subsequent code *use* those calculated `name` and `prefs` values? *Should* it? Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and teach yourself to find these kinds of oversights.

Comment: Also, try to title your questions according to the problem *that you are experiencing*, rather than the overall task you are trying to accomplish. Since you are expected to make your best attempt to diagnose and research the problem first anyway, use a question title that reflects your understanding of what the problem is. See [ask] for more.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue here is that you are using `rstrip` on a copy of the data but never apply it to the original.

## The issue

```
for movie in movietitles:
    movie=movie.rstrip() # Changes the (copy) of the data rather than the original
    # We still need to apply this back to movietitles
```

## There are a couple ways to fix this!

```
# Using indexing
for _ in range(len(movietitles)):
    movietitles[_] = movietitles[_].rstrip()
```

## Or we can do this inline with list comprehension

```
# Using list comprehension
movietitles = [movie.rstrip() for movie in movietitles]
```

As stated in the other answer, when working with csv data it's recomended to use a csv parser, but completely unnecessary for this scale! Hope this helps